# JavaScript Query on Optionset

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

How can I save the remaining optionset items after removing an item from the list? Is there any other way of adding the removed option from an optionset in XRM?

```js
function func1() {

    var A1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attribute1").getValue();
    var B1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attribute2").getValue();
    var PickListA1 = Xrm.Page.getControl("attribute1");
    var PickListA1Options = PickListA1.getAttribute().getOptions();
    var j = 0;

    if (B1 == "3") {
        if (A1 == "1") {
            PickListA1.clearOptions();
            for (var i in PickListA1Options) {
                if (PickListA1Options[i].value != "null") {
                    PickListA1.addOption(PickListA1Options[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        PickListA1.removeOption(1);
    }
    else {
        PickListA1.getAttribute().setvalue(A1);
        for (var i in PickListA1Options) {
            if (PickListA1Options[i].value == "1") {
                break;
            }
            else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (j > 1) {
            PickListA1.addOption(PickListA1Options[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my code above. Actually the for loop in my else part is not working. Like PickListA1Options is not reloaded with the options after removing 1. It is always having all the options so it is finding option item 1 so, never adding the option 1 again. Whereas at UI level option 1 which is been removed on selection of B1 == "3", is never visible on selection of other B1 items. my requirement is for B1 alone A1 option 1 should not appear in the list, for all other B1 options it should show the A1 option 1.